# What are the differences between the resutls of Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype) and Dog.prototype = {...Animal.prototype}?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototype

What are the differences between the resutls of  `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)` and `Dog.prototype = {...Animal.prototype}` ?

Comment: There are lots of differences. You would find out some by mere testing with a simple class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several differences, including:

- `{...Animal.prototype}` will create a separate prototype that lives its own life, unaware of property assignments that might be brought to `Animal.prototype`
- `{...Animal.prototype}` only copies *enumerable* properties, and as some methods might not be, you'll miss out on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new object (using the shallow copy abilities of the spread operator), then changes to the original object will not be applied to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface level, one is just copying *properties*, the other is basically creating a *new* copy of the `Animal`:

[image]

The destructuring copy also copies all *references* in the source object, so changes on `Dog` could then affect `Animal`, which probably isn't what you want.